# preg_match() regex pattern for my url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I tried to make a pattern for this url:

```
http://media.network.com/flv/ea03addc753ff8d80f6be4b49a414cfd/4f3d2012/5016.flv
```

I just want to retrive the numbers 5016 - `fileid` from the url.. so i used this code

```
preg_match( '#http://media\.gilmanetwork\.com/flv/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.flv#', $markup, $matches );
```

so if i use `$matches[3]`, I should get the number 5016 right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a big mistake there. `gilmanetwork` versus `network`. Try

```
'#http://media.network.com/flv/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.flv#'
```

Which results in

```
<?php
$markup = "http://media.network.com/flv/ea03addc753ff8d80f6be4b49a414cfd/4f3d2012/5016.flv";
preg_match( '#http://media.network.com/flv/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.flv#', $markup, $matches );
print_r($matches);
// Array ( [0] => http://media.network.com/flv/ea03addc753ff8d80f6be4b49a414cfd/4f3d2012/5016.flv [1] => ea03addc753ff8d80f6be4b49a414cfd [2] => 4f3d2012 [3] => 5016 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url), combined with [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo):

```
$url      = 'http://media.network.com/flv/ea03addc753ff8d80f6be4b49a414cfd/4f3d2012/5016.flv';
$filename = pathinfo(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), PATHINFO_FILENAME);

echo $filename;  // 5016
```

This approach has an advantage over regular expressions in that the format of the URL can change - and potentially pretty extensively – but so long as the filename of the resource is its ID number, this code will always produce the correct result.